# Set main record (for a one to many relationship) per group

Tags: triggers, sql-server-2008-r2

**Background**

I have two tables with a one to many relationship (Companies.ID (1) to Addresses.CompanyID (N)). The Addresses table also has a column "Mainaddress" which is of type 'bit'.

**Example Data**

Companies:

```
ID | Name
1  | Company1
2  | Company2
```

Addresses:

```
ID | CompanyID | MainAddress
1  | 1         | true
2  | 1         | false
3  | 1         | false
4  | 2         | false
5  | 2         | true
```

**What I want to achieve**

Every company must have one (and only one) main address. Every time the "MainAddress" column gets updated I need to make sure that this requirement is still fulfilled. Scenarios:

1. Address record with ID 2 becomes main address --> MainAddress for Address with ID 1 must be set to false
2. MainAddress for Address record with ID 1 gets set from true to false --> if it is the only record for this company it needs to be set to true again, otherwise one of the other records becomes the main address (doesn't matter which one)
3. Both the Addresses with ID 2 & 3 become the main address --> MainAddress for one of the two (doesn't matter which) must be set to true, every other MainAddress for this company must be set to false
4. The record with MainAddress = true is deleted --> one of the other records for this company must become the main address (again, doesn't matter which one)
5. A new record with MainAddress = true is inserted --> every other MainAddress for this company must be set to false

The difficult part is that this also has to work if I update every address at once and the points above have to be applied to every company individually.

**Current solution**

I have a database trigger that runs after Insert, Update, Delete which creates a cursor for every CompanyID in the inserted or deleted table:

```
INSERT INTO #Temp_SetMainAddress
SELECT DISTINCT "CompanyID" FROM inserted;

DECLARE reccursor CURSOR STATIC FORWARD_ONLY READ_ONLY FOR
SELECT ID
FROM #Temp_SetMainAddress
```

And then applies changes according to the 5 points above for each company individually.

**Question**

I wonder if this can be achieved without relying on a cursor? As it is I am worried about the performance (if I update about 7000 addresses it already takes about 20 seconds).
I tried to think of ways to do this in another way but I didn't come up with anything so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been 6 weeks since you ask the question, but I just have too much time this evening and enjoyed a bit of puzzle. So here's my solution using triggers.

### A few words before we start:

1. Using a trigger to update a table after a user-issued update is dangerous, since it will cause the trigger to be called again, which updates the table again... In short: an infinite loop.Tthe buck must stop somewhere. For this I'm adding a column to the `Addresses` table: `FireTrigger`. If this is true, the trigger will update the table. Otherwise, the trigger will do nothing.
2. I changed the PK name on the `Addresses` table to `AddressesID`. `ID` just drove me nuts.
3. You didn't specify a rule on which address should be chosen as the Main Address in case multiple addresses are set as such. My rule is that the lowest `AddressID` is chosen as the Main Address in case multiple addresses are specified as Main for a company.
4. It hasn't been rigorously tested. There are likely bugs in some edge cases, but you get the idea.

And this is my solution:

### Trigger on Insert and Update

```
CREATE TRIGGER Addresses_OnInsertUpdate
    ON Addresses
    AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @tmp TABLE (CompanyID int, MainAddressID int)

    ;WITH cte1 AS
    (
        SELECT  AddressID, CompanyID,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CompanyID ORDER BY AddressID) AS RowNumber
        FROM    inserted
        WHERE   MainAddress = 1
            AND FireTrigger = 1
    )

    INSERT INTO @tmp (CompanyID, MainAddressID)
        SELECT  CompanyID, AddressID
        FROM    cte1
        WHERE   RowNumber = 1

    ;WITH cte2 AS
    (
        SELECT      i.CompanyID
        FROM        inserted    i
        LEFT  JOIN  Addresses   a ON i.CompanyID = a.CompanyID
                                 AND a.MainAddress = 1
        WHERE       i.FireTrigger = 1
        GROUP BY    i.CompanyID
        HAVING      COUNT(a.AddressID) = 0
    ),
    cte3 AS
    (
        SELECT      d.CompanyID, d.AddressID
        FROM        deleted     d
        INNER JOIN  cte2        c2 ON d.CompanyID = c2.CompanyID
        WHERE       d.MainAddress = 1
    ),
    cte4 AS
    (
        SELECT      i.CompanyID, i.AddressID,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY i.CompanyID ORDER BY i.AddressID) AS RowNumber
        FROM        inserted    i
        INNER JOIN  cte2        c2 ON i.CompanyID = c2.CompanyID
    )

    INSERT INTO @tmp (CompanyID, MainAddressID)
        SELECT  CompanyID, AddressID
        FROM    cte3
        UNION
        SELECT  CompanyID, AddressID
        FROM    cte4
        WHERE   RowNumber = 1


    UPDATE Addresses
        SET         MainAddress = CASE a.AddressID
                                    WHEN MainAddressID THEN 1
                                    ELSE 0
                                  END,
                    FireTrigger = 0
        FROM        Addresses   a
        INNER JOIN  @tmp        tmp ON a.CompanyID = tmp.CompanyID
END
```

The `@tmp` table decides what `AddressID` is chosen as main **after** the table has been updated to the user's specification.

1. `cte1` deals with the case where one/multiple addresses are set as Main by the user. In that case, it choses the lowest `AddressID` of those for the final Main Address.
2. `cte2` finds companies without a main address after an insert/update. There are two reason for this to happen: you set the current Main Address to false (see `cte3`) or you inserted a brand-new company with Main Address = false (see `cte4`)
3. `cte3` digs out the `AddressID` of the previous Main Address.
4. `cte4` gets the lowest `AddressID` for newly inserted companies without a main address.

Adding rows from `cte1`, `cte3` and `cte4` together gives you the main `AddressID` of each company that has been subjected to an insert / update. To fire the trigger, you must set `FireTrigger` to true:

```
INSERT INTO Addresses (..., FireTrigger)
    VALUES (...., 1)

UPDATE Adddresses
    SET ..., FireTrigger = 1
    WHERE ...
```

### Trigger on Delete

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.Addresses_OnDelete
    ON dbo.Addresses
    AFTER DELETE
AS
BEGIN
    ;WITH cte2 AS
    (
        SELECT      d.CompanyID
        FROM        deleted     d
        LEFT JOIN   Addresses   a ON d.CompanyID = a.CompanyID
                                 AND a.MainAddress = 1
        GROUP BY    d.CompanyID
        HAVING      COUNT(a.AddressID) = 0
    ),
    cte3 AS
    (
        SELECT      a.CompanyID, a.AddressID,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.CompanyID ORDER BY a.AddressID) AS RowNumber
        FROM        cte2        c2
        INNER JOIN  Addresses   a   ON c2.CompanyID = a.CompanyID
    )

    UPDATE Addresses
        SET         MainAddress = 1,
                    FireTrigger = 0
        FROM        Addresses   a
        INNER JOIN  cte3        c3 ON a.CompanyID = c3.CompanyID
                                  AND a.AddressID = c3.AddressID
        WHERE       c3.RowNumber = 1
END
```

This is simpler than the other trigger:

1. Again, `cte2` finds the companies without a Main Address (there's no `cte1`—it's not a typo).
2. `cte3` selects the *lowest remaining* `AddressID` for the Main Address